# Where can I find the meaning in English , of Shree Rudram Laghunyasam?

Tags: shiva, krishna-yajurveda, rudram

I have found the meaning of Shree rudram Namakam and Chamakam on net already but The Laghunyasam part is not available with English Meaning or commentary anywhere as I have searched. If anybody can refer a book, that too will be helpful.

Comment: The main vedic portion comes from katakam (काठकम्), one can find it in [Taittiriya Brahmana](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/taittirIyabrAhmaNam.html) . Look [This](https://www.scribd.com/document/346834040/Laghunysam-Body-Parts) .